# Moving Dataloader data to GPU PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am just getting started with PyTorch...

Currently I am following this method of getting training data to the GPU. Source: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel

```
# Loop over epochs
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    # Training
    for local_batch, local_labels in training_generator:
        # Transfer to GPU
        local_batch, local_labels = local_batch.to(device), local_labels.to(device)

        # Model computations
        [...]
```

**Question**: This seems less efficient than just loading the entire data set onto the GPU. Does loading data on each batch not cause latency? Am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing the fact that the entire dataset often does not fit in RAM memory, let alone GPU memory.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The CPU loads data into the GPU at every mini-batch. There are tricks in PyTorch (and other frameworks) which enable them to load the data in parallel processes to reduce the latency to some extent. Look at [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#multi-process-data-loading) in the docs.